# How to create end date that is one day less than the next start date created by another another query with sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, subquery

I queried off of a table that pulls in anyone who has working time percentage of less than 100 and all their working time records if they met the less than 100 criteria.

This table contains the columns: `id`, `eff_date` (of working time percentage), and `percentage`. This table does not contain `end_date`.

Problem: how to build on top of the query below and add a new column called `end_date` that is one date less than the next `eff_date`?

**Current query**

```
select 
    j1.id, j1.eff_date,  j1.percentage
from 
    working_time_table j1
where 
    exists (select 1
            from working_time_table j2
            where j2.id = j1.id and j2.percentage < 100)
```

Data returned from the query above:

```
ID | EFF_DATE| PERCENTAGE
------------------------
12 | 01-JUN-2012 |  70
12 | 03-MAR-2013 | 100
12 | 13-DEC-2014 |  85
```

The desired result set is:

```
ID | EFF_DATE    | PERCENTAGE | END_DATE
-------------------------------------------
12 | 01-JUN-2012 |     70     | 02-MAR-2013
12 | 03-MAR-2013 |    100     | 12-DEC-2014
12 | 13-DEC-2014 |     85     | null
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL using [window functions](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql):

```
select j1.id, 
       j1.eff_date,
       j1.percentage, 
       lead(j1.eff_date) over (partition by j1.id order by j1.eff_date) - interval '1' day as end_date
from working_time_table j1
where exists (select 1
              from working_time_table j2
              where j2.id = j1.id and j2.percentage < 100);
```

Comment: what if I need the null value of end_date to be either the termination date if there is one? Would the above query work as well?

Answer (score 0):

> First off, curious if the "id" column is unique or it has duplicate values like the 12's in your sample, or is that a unique column or primary key possibly.   It would be WAAAAY easier to do this if there was a unique
>   id column that held the order.   If you don't have a unique ID column,
>    are you able to add one to the table?   Again, would simplify this
>   tremendously.
>
> ---

This took forever to get right,  I hope this helps,  burned many hours on it.
Props to Akhil for helping me finally get the query right.   He is a true SQL genius.

Here is the ..

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e4c5/117)

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    firstTbl.eff_Date, 
    UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(
        STR_TO_DATE(secondTbl.eff_Date, '%d-%M-%Y'), 
            INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d-%b-%Y')) todate, 
    percentage FROM 
    (SELECT 
        (@cnt := @cnt + 1) rownum, 
        id, eff_date, percentage 
     FROM working_time_table, 
     (SELECT 
         @cnt := 0) s) firstTbl
      LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT 
              (@cnt1 := @cnt1 + 1) rownum, 
              eff_date 
           FROM working_time_table, 
               (SELECT 
                   @cnt1 := 0) s) secondTbl
                ON (firstTbl.rownum + 1) = secondTbl.rownum
```

Comment: the id is unique per person but each record of working time does not correspond to an unique record

Comment: and thank you very much for spending so much time on it; it is greatly appreciated